# how to populate a dropdown menu using JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to populate a dropdown box based on the selection of another dropdown.

I have create a sample variable `var sampleData = { Default: { value1: "text", value2: "text" }, PTDR:`  in order to find the second dropdown populates itself once the user selects the first dropdown which seems to be working. However, I am trying to correct data from a method in my controller which I don't know how to.

any help help or guidance would be appreciated.

```
public ActionResult ptdrFilter(int id)
    {
        IUnitOfWork uow = DataAccess.GetUnitOfWork();
        using (ManageProductTemplate ptLogic = new ManageProductTemplate(ref uow))
        {
            List<ProductTemplate> currentpt = ptLogic.GetBy(x => x.ProductTemplateID == id);
            List<string> pt = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in currentpt)
            {
                pt.Add(item.DistributionRule.Name);

            }
            return Json(pt);
        }
    }


    function drFilter() {

            var sampleData = { Default: { value1: "text", value2: "text" }, PTDR: { value1: "cal", value2: "cal" }, All: { value1: "lool", value2: "loool" } };
            var dataInJSONForm = JSON.stringify(sampleData);
            var datainJSObjectForm = JSON.parse(dataInJSONForm);

            $('#dd1').on('change', function (e) {
                var valueChosenInddl2 = $(this).val();
                var options = datainJSObjectForm[valueChosenInddl2];



                var $subselect = $('#subselect');
                $subselect.children().detach();
                for (var property in options) {
                    $subselect.append($('<option>', { value: property, text: options[property] }));

<div class="editor-field">
                <select id="dd1">
                  <option value="Default">Default</option>
                  <option value="PTDR">PT/DR</option>
                  <option value="All">All</option>
                </select>

<select id="ddl2">
                    <script>
                        drFilter();
                    </script>
                </select>
```

Comment: provide your html

Comment: i have updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an ajax request to go get the data from the controller, something like this should work so that on success the json object from the controller is passed into your function and can be used instead of sampleData.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: {id: 1},
    url: @Action.Url("ptdrFilter"),
    success: function(result) {
        drFilter(result);
    }
});
```